# how to reslove wrong username and password error in h2 database and springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, h2db

Properties used in application.properties

```
server.port=8085
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver 
spring.datasource.username=root 
spring.datasource.password=root 
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect 
spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update 
spring.h2.console.enabled=true 
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
```

Error
how to reslove wrong username and password error in h2 database and springboot?

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Wrong user name or password [28000-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:461) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:170) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.validateUserAndPassword(Engine.java:357) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:176) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:166) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:29) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:340) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:173) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:152) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.lambda$h2Console$0(H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.java:73) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
```

Comment: ->application.properties file      :-
server.port=8085
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

Comment: Please see my answer below as I came here with the same problem but found a fix. stackoverflow.com/a/74924258/398348

Answer (score 8):

Try to delete DB files (test.mv.db and test.trace.db).
Maybe you have created it before and used for it different credentials.

Comment: Is it possible to read the H2 backup created with a different user ? Assume that I want to update my existing H2 DB Password. Would I still be able to read the backups created with old credentials ?

Answer (score 0):

When I followed the (wrong) advice to remove the saved setting, the "Generic H2", is deleted from the dropdown options menu (see below). I could not add it again.

[image: removed settings]

So I went to the H2database site and found the FAQ
https://h2database.com/html/faq.html#support

> ***Where are the Database Files Stored?*** When using database URLs like
> jdbc:h2:~/test, the database is stored in the user directory. For
> Windows, this is usually C:\Documents and Settings<userName> or
> C:\Users<userName>. If the base directory is not set (as in
> jdbc:h2:./test), the database files are stored in the directory where
> the application is started (the current working directory). When using
> the H2 Console application from the start menu, this is /bin. The base directory can be set in the database URL. A
> fixed or relative path can be used. When using the URL
> jdbc:h2:file:./data/sample, the database is stored in the directory
> data (relative to the current working directory). The directory is
> created automatically if it does not yet exist. It is also possible to
> use the fully qualified directory name (and for Windows, drive name).
> Example: jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/test

I went to C:Users/Me and found these 3 files. I deleted them, rebuilt my SpringBoot app and voila!

[image: h2 db files]

[image: fixed]

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me:

[image: H2 console screenshot]

1. Remove and re-add Saved Setting and Setting Name
   [*Generic H2(Embedded)*] (see screenshot above)
2. Make sure the JDBC URL, Username, Password match your application properties.
3. Update, build and restart Spring Boot Application.

Also, delete browser history, cache, etc.,

Sample Application. Properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:dcbapp
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: This is wrong advice. When I removed the Generic H2, it is deleted from the dropdown options menu. I cannot add it again. See my answer for the correct fix.

Answer (score -1):

this is can be seen  in the console output when the project run

H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at
'jdbc:h2:mem:75b0b22c-4101-47e1-ab12-367c85ae18f5' this part is should type to JBDC URL area. Then you can access the H2-console

Comment: the question is asking about username and password